# How to easily find out which Google App Engine project is mapped to a custom domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I want to be able to generate a report of custom domains is a Google App Engine instance mapped to.

It is because I have a number of google app engine projects which are mapped to various different domains. There is no rule how these projects are mapped to domains. Instead of using the Google Cloud Platform and iterate through each playground, is there an easier to interrogate GCP and retrieve a mapping between instance and custom domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to do something like that. Although, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/67023574) opened for this.